# Having trouble creating a list of urls by slicing

Tags: regex, xpath, web-crawler, slice, href

So I've been stuck on this homework problem and don't seem to be getting anywhere:/...I'm trying to create a new URL list that contains the proper URLs for the top 10 movies, here's my code so far:

`tree = html.fromstring(response.content)`

`titles = [tree.xpath("//a/text()")]`

`urls = [tree.xpath("//td[@class='titleColumn']//a/@href")]`

`top10_urls = urls[:10]`

`top10_urls_fixed = []`

`for t in top10_urls:`

`if len(t) > 0:`

`t = "https://www.imdb.com"+ urls`

```
    top10_urls_fixed.append(t)
```

***my URLs are currently displaying like `'/title/tt0111161/'`, and I'm trying to insert `'https://www.imdb.com'` in front of each URL, so they look like `'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/'`.

With labs being online now my professor never answers his emails and I'm stuck waiting all day, any help would be amazing TT-TT

Comment: Because this is Python, you really need to correct your indentation so that others can more easily assess and answer your problem(s).  The entire chunk of code should be in a single multi-line {} markup segment in StackOverflow. What you did is marked up every line separately.  As it is, it looks like the main logic problem is the line with t = ...  In it you are trying to concatenate a string with a list.

Comment: I see, thank you for the feedback, its my first time here on stack overflow so I was confused how to input my code!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a mistake here:

```
t = "https://www.imdb.com"+ urls
```

Should be:

```
t = "https://www.imdb.com"+ t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example with IMDB. We extract the urls of each recommandation from a starting page. After getting the `@href` attributes (stored in a list), we paste the beginning of the url with the `+` operator inside a loop.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
movie_recs = tree.xpath('//div[@class="rec_overlay"]/following::a[1]/@href')
urls =["https://www.imdb.com" + el for el in movie_recs]
print (urls)
```

Output :

[image: Movies Rec]

Comment: Thank you so much, our prof ended up telling us the answer and his way was soooo long and obnoxious! you are a life saver I was able to share this way with the class.

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if your problem is solved. Successful continuation !